# Body Parser issue with Express, React. Posting Null values in database

Tags: reactjs, express, body-parser

Middleware issue with body-parser:
The data gets stored as an object which later calls /api/new to post in SQL database.

No Issues with the query itself but data has null values in the database.

My thoughts:

1. app.use(express.urlencoded({
   extended: true
   }));
   is set to true, as some values are INT,
2. I tried JSON.Stringify the data before it gets sent to the POST request. Did not work
3. Also played around with the header

   // const config = {
   //   headers: {
   //     accept: "application/json",
   //     "accept-language": "en_US",
   //     "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   //   }
   // };

axios.post("/api/new",{newEntry}, config ...

4. I think the issue may be due to the fact that its router.post in my api-routes instead of app.post

   `````
   ```
        var newEntry = {
             First_Name: FirstName.toUpperCase(),
             Last_Name: LastName.toUpperCase(),
             Employ_ID: parseInt(EmployID),
             Problem: checkedValue,
             PhoneNumber: phoneNumber,
             Provider: domain
           };
           var stringNewEntry = JSON.stringify(newEntry);

           console.log("Right before Post");
           console.log(newEntry);

           axios
             .post(
               "/api/new",
              {newEntry},
               {
                 timeout: 10000
               }
             )
             .catch(error => {
               if (error.code === "ECONNABORTED") return "timeout";
             })
             .then(res => {
               console.log(newEntry);
               if (res === "timeout") {
                 console.log("Please Try Again");
               } else {
                 console.log("SUCCESS!");
               }
             });
         }
   ````
   `````

   Server File

   ```
       const express = require("express");
       const app = express();
       var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

       const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
       var routes = require("./routes/api-routes");
       // Define middleware here

       app.use(express.json());
       app.use(bodyParser.json());
       app.use(express.urlencoded({
         extended: true
       }));

       // Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
       if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
         app.use(express.static("client/build"));
       }
       // Add routes, both API and view
       app.use(routes);

       // Start the API server
       app.listen(PORT, function() {
         console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
       });
   ```

api-routes

```
    router.route("/api/new").post(function(req, res) {
  console.log("Data:");

  console.log(req.body.First_Name);

  var dbQuery =
    "INSERT INTO KioskInfo (First_Name,Last_name,Employ_ID,Problem,PhoneNumber,Provider) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  var dbQueryPermanent =
    "INSERT INTO KioskData (First_Name,Last_name,Employ_ID,Problem) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
  var IgnoreQuery =
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO KioskInfo (First_Name,Last_name,Employ_ID,Problem,PhoneNumber,Provider) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

  connection.query(
    dbQuery,
    [
      req.body.First_Name,
      req.body.Last_Name,
      req.body.Employ_ID,
      req.body.Problem,
      req.body.PhoneNumber,
      req.body.Provider
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        connection.query(
          IgnoreQuery,
          [
            req.body.First_Name,
            req.body.Last_Name,
            req.body.Employ_ID,
            req.body.Problem,
            req.body.PhoneNumber,
            req.body.Provider
          ],
          function(IgnErr, IgnResult) {
            if (IgnErr) {
              throw IgnErr;
            } else {
              console.log("Duplicate Entry Ignored");
            }
          }
        );
      }
      //Learn to specify DUP ERR;
      console.log("Successfully Saved Into KioskInfo");
    }
  );

  connection.query(
    dbQueryPermanent,
    [
      req.body.First_Name,
      req.body.Last_Name,
      req.body.Employ_ID,
      req.body.Problem
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Successfully Saved Into KioskData");
      res.end();
    }
  );
});
```